# AngularJS - set default multi select drop down value from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS multi select drop down code from the following source:
[MultiSelectDropDown](http://embed.plnkr.co/xWvfWYjaW7TThKZONkv5/)

I am using the same drop down twice in the same html page. I want to display the default selected drop down name of first multi select drop down as "Projects" and the second as "Environments".

The code in the multiselect.js file is using a directive and `scope.header` is set to "Select" as default and i want to change the default name "Select" to "Projects" and "Environments" in my html page.

I need your help to update it either using multiselect syntax in html page or from the controller to pass the scope.header value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

The string value 'Select' is hardcoded into the directive. You will need to modify the code to make it dynamic.

## Code

Here how I changed it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/J4CBblcfdDcrvE6K?preview

### Index.html

I added the header attribute with the text I wanted it to show.

#### Lines 17-24

```html
  <multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true"
        ng-model="selectedCar"
        header="Cars"
        options="c.name for c in cars"
        change="selected()" ></multiselect>
        <div class="well well-small">
            {{selectedCar}}
        </div>
```

### multiselect.js

I made the scope.header set to the attribute and default to 'Select' if nothing is given.

#### Line 45

```js
scope.header = attrs.header || 'Select';
```

#### Line 119

```js
if (!modelCtrl.$modelValue || !modelCtrl.$modelValue.length) return scope.header = attrs.header || 'Select';
```

Comment: Brilliant coding. It works as expected. I have a problem with the css where class "icon-ok" and "icon-remove" in multiselect.tmpl.html file is not working. The check marks don't show up in the UI. The "checkAll" and "UncheckAll" button work as expected but the tick marks disappeared. Could you please help me in fixing the problem.

Comment: I have downloaded the entire project.zip file, extracted and copied to htdocs directory in apache web server. The offline copy is not showing the tick marks but its working in the plunker link.

Comment: Sure, i can create a new question. Thanks for the help.